# Dynamically create pages with Gatsby based on many Contentful references

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I am currently using Gatsby's [collection routes API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/file-system-route-api/#collection-routes) to create pages for a simple blog with data coming from Contentful.

For example, creating a page for each blogpost category :

```
-- src/pages/categories/{contentfulBlogPost.category}.js

export const query = graphql`
  query categoriesQuery($category: String = "") {
    allContentfulBlogPost(filter: { category: { eq: $category } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          category
          description {
            description
          }
        ...
        }
      }
    }
  }

...
[React component mapping all blogposts from each category in a list]
...
```

This is working fine.

But now I would like to have multiple categories per blogpost, so I switched to Contentful's `references, many` content-type, which allows to have multiple entries for a field :

[image: contentful content-model for blogposts]

Now the result of my graphQL query on field `category2` is an array of different categories for each blogpost :

Query :

```
query categoriesQuery {
  allContentfulBlogPost {
    edges {
      node {
        category2 {
          id
          name
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output :

```
{
  "data": {
    "allContentfulBlogPost": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "category2": [
              {
                "id": "75b89e48-a8c9-54fd-9742-cdf70c416b0e",
                "name": "Test",
                "slug": "test"
              },
              {
                "id": "568r9e48-t1i8-sx4t8-9742-cdf70c4ed789vtu",
                "name": "Test2",
                "slug": "test-2"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "category2": [
              {
                "id": "75b89e48-a8c9-54fd-9742-cdf70c416b0e",
                "name": "Test",
                "slug": "test"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
...
```

Now that categories are inside an array, I don't know how to :

- write a *query variable* to filter categories names ;
- use the slug field as a route to dynamically create the page.

For blogposts authors I was doing :

```
  query authorsQuery($author__slug: String = "") {
    allContentfulBlogPost(filter: { author: { slug: { eq: $author__slug } } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          author {
            slug
            name
          }
          ...
        }
      ...
      }
```

And creating pages with `src/pages/authors/{contentfulBlogPost.author__slug}.js`

I guess I'll have to use the createPages API instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the result using the Filesystem API, something like this may work:

```
src/pages/category/{contentfulBlogPost.category2__name}.js
```

In this case, it seems that this approach may lead to some caveats, since you may potentially create duplicated pages with the same URL (`slug`) because the posts can contain multiple and repeated categories.

However, I think it's more succinct to use the `createPages` API as you said, keeping in mind that you will need to treat the categories to avoid duplicities because they are in a *one-to-many* relationship.

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
     allContentfulBlogPost {
        edges {
          node {
            category2 {
              id
              name
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  
  let categories= { slugs: [], names: [] };

  result.data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.map(({node}))=> {
   let { name, slug } = node.category2;
   // make some checks if needed here

    categories.slugs.push(slug);
    categories.names.push(name);

    return new Set(categories.slugs) && new Set(categories.names);
  });

  categories.slugs.forEach((category, index) => {
    let name = categories.names[index];

    createPage({
      path: `category/${category}`,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/your-category-template.js`),
      context: {
        name
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The code's quite self-explanatory. Basically you are defining an empty object (`categories`) that contains two arrays, `slugs` and `names`:

```
  let categories= { slugs: [], names: [] };
```

After that, you only need to loop through the result of the query (`result`) and push the field values (`name`, `slug`, and others if needed) to the previous array, making the needed checks if you want (to avoid pushing empty values, or that matches some regular expression, etc) and return a `new Set` to remove the duplicates.

Then, you only need to loop through the slugs to create pages using `createPage` API and pass the needed data via context:

```
  context: {
    name
  }
```

Because of redundancy, this is the same than doing:

```
  context: {
    name: name
  }
```

So, in your template, you will get the name in `pageContext` `props`. Replace it with the `slug` if needed, depending on your situation and your use case, the approach is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer !